# How to implement voice & text chat between two iOS device

Tags: objective-c, ios, text, chat, voice

I want to implement an app by which voice & text chat between two iOS devcices under a network become possible. I dont need voice call facility to any phone like LinPhone or SiPhone. I have studied over them & found too complex for me. Is there any simple SDK to make this possible???

By the way, user identification may be done by e-mail verification....

Answer (score 1):

I think one best way to do it using XMPP Framework. Using XMPP you can send files & text to other persons. Using it you can record voice message & send it across. There are some links for it:

**[GitHub Project Link for XMPP Chat](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS)**

**[Building a Jabber Client for iOS: XMPP Setup](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-integration/)**

Hope it helps to you.

**EDIT:**

Apple's GameKit framework provides evertyhing you need to implement in-game chat.

The full documentation is here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/AddingVoiceChattoaMatch/AddingVoiceChattoaMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH11-SW11

Assuming you have allready connected the App to one or more other players using GameKit, you can start the voice chat like so:

```
-(void) startInGameChat {
//Set up audio session
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:myErr];
[audioSession setActive: YES error: myErr];

GKMatch* match;
GKVoiceChat *teamChannel = [[match voiceChatWithName:@"redTeam"] retain];
GKVoiceChat *allChannel = [[match voiceChatWithName:@"allPlayers"] retain];

//Start the chat
[teamChannel start];

//Enable Mic
teamChannel.active = YES;

}
```

Comment: Thnx for your response. I have seen through your links and wonder that are they voice supported??

Comment: No, That are not voice supported. But might be you can build a logic to send voice recording in a file & vice versa.

Comment: Check this too. I have added a GameKit Method to send voice too.