# How to make voice chat between two application over internet?

Tags: ios, voip, phone-call, livechat

How can the app in two devices can contact to each other through Internet? In my app, I want the option of calling the other user within the app,ie., it should not use the regular calling service through mobile network(like in apps like Viber, Tango).Is there any framework available for both text chat and voice call? Please suggest some framework to achieve the both functionality.

**Note:**

1.For text chat, my opinion is go with Remote Notification service? Is this the best way to do? please suggest if any other best solutions available.

2.Regarding call service, I don't have any idea.

3.But the thing is, everything should be free.User should needed only internet connection.

Thank you.

Comment: try this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250498/how-to-implement-voice-text-chat-between-two-ios-device

Comment: @kirtimali Ya I already checked that S.O question. But it was suggested that, it is good only for text chat.But I need both functionality.

Comment: @NSUserDefault : did you got any idea about voice calling?

Comment: Have you got any solution..?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. push notifications are the best way. find a nice tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)
2. For voice chat, [Twilio Client iOS VoIP SDK](http://www.twilio.com/client)

   will be the best choice. It will also support text chatting. You can find docs also here.
3. Dont worry. Everything is free. enjoy coding

Comment: Is there any other way to do text chat? and thanks for your response.

Comment: Ok I will check the link given by you.

Comment: I checked that link and its given as some charges for making call.What I want is, user should make a call within app with free of cost.Please refer app link Viber and Tango.I need the same functionality.

Comment: Your text chat won't work at all if user disables Push Notifications on a device for an app